# Adding glow to border-style dotted

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a question regarding on styling the border-style: dotted.

What I want to achieve is adding the glow on each of the circle/dot. Is it possible or achievable?
Since each time I try to add the glow effect, it will go directly towards whole edge of the div border.

[image]

I would like to add glow effect to those tiny little dots.

Hope anyone could enlighten me on this matter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a drop-shadow filter:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:30px 80px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  inset:0;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:10px dotted red;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 3px green);
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text
</div>
```

Even a blur filter can work to give a different output:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:30px 80px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  inset:0;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:10px dotted red;
  filter:blur(2px);
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text
</div>
```